# Is there a working solution to produce PDF/A-1b with MiKTeX?

Tags: pdftex, miktex, publishing, pdf-a, archiving

I have read a lot of interesting questions and answers on PDF/A-1b production with LaTeX and pdfTeX. I still can't produce validating PDF/A-1b files.

I used either:

- the standard up-to-date `pdfx` package
- or the "improved" 
  [pdfx-ext](https://github.com/bencomp/pdfx-ext) version,
- or the edited `pdfx.sty` by Vincent Immler two years ago, (see [here](http://sarovar.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=4341&group_id=106&atid=493)
  and the attached [sample](http://www.sarovar.org/tracker/download.php/106/493/4341/10821/verify_this_sample.zip_)).

I encountered no compiling errors, and validation with [jhove](http://jhove.sourceforge.net)  always works

However file validation fails by :

- Acrobat X Pro preflight,
- online validation provided by [3-Height pdf-tools](http://www.pdf-tools.com/pdf/validate-pdfa-online.aspx)
- online validation provided by [Solid PDF Tools](http://www.validatepdfa.com/online.htm)

As I was not able to patch `pdftex` as suggested by Vincent Immler, I managed to repair de EOL problems reported in several posts on `tex.stackexchange.com` by using binary replacements of `x32` or `x0a` with the `gsar` utility, in order to mimic the changes made in the patch.

However the error messages :

```
The separator before 'endstream' must be an EOL.
```

is still present, with further error messages looking as overvall failure conclusion.

- Has someone succeeded to patch MiKTeX's pdftex ?
- Does this patch fix the all the `EOL` problems (including the `endstream` one)?
- Is there a 'package only' solution ?

*I use MiKTeX v 2.9 (pdftex Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14) on both Windows XP Pro x32 (SP3)
and Windows Seven Family Premium x64 (SP1)*

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on our [our starter page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) to familiarize yourself further with our format. A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (`{}`) or hit Ctrl+K.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer posted as a comment on November 10th 2016 :

Finally, with the latest version of MiKTeX (pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (MiKTeX 2.9) and pdfx (v1.5.4) it works out of the box.

Comment: Hey, you sticked to your question for almost six years! I don't know whether any other issue was solved here on SX after such a long time.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the provided patch I was able to reproduce correct PDFA-1b PDFs some time ago using TeXLive. I do not see why MiKTeX should be any different.

Your approach does not address the specific issue related to how pdf streams are terminated. With the default pdftex, they are terminated using `0x0A`, they should be however terminated using `0x0D 0x0A` (together, 13 and 10 in decimal). At least, all validation tools I used stopped complaining. I doubt that a simple search and replace will do here (this may effect the length information of the stream written), neither will there be a package-only solution for this.

The other two problems are somewhat related. I would suggest adding your problems to the bug report or try contacting the original author of the provided patch (if possible).

Comment: My problem to patch `MiKTeX` is not at all in the  `.web` file, but the awfull problem to set up a working environment for `M$-Vicual C++` compilation. 

In fact, what I tried is the replacement of `0x0A`  by `0x0D` because I din't see the `0x0A0x0D` string before endstream in a working PDF. Of course an insertion (ie 1 char -> 2chars, also tried) corrupt definitely the PDF.

Comment: I would assume the only way to compile pdftex for Windows is to use minGW. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW

Comment: Yes, I'm much more used to `MinGW` than `M$-Visual C++`. But on `MiKTeX` website there is nothing else than the `M$` solution.
Shall I switch to `TeXLive`, which seems yo be build-able with `MinGW` ?

Comment: pdftex is separate from MikTeX. You can download it as a source archive from here: http://www.tug.org/applications/pdftex/ . Using Linux it is quite easy ... :-)

Comment: Thank You for suggestion, but build of pdfTeX with (up to date) MinGW stop at the end with error code :

    pc     pdftex.p   -o pdftex
    /bin/bash: pc: command not found
    make: *** [pdftex] Error 127
By the way I have posted on miktex-users list....

Comment: @jhor - just curious if you got pdfTeX to compile (w MinGW)?

Comment: @infowanna : yes, PC stands for "pascal compiler", and i finally found a workaround, but i do'nt remember what was the solution :-( Furthermore, the need of producing a PDF/A finally desappeared !

Comment: Finally, with the latest version of MiKTeX 
(pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (MiKTeX 2.9)
and pdfx (v1.5.4) it works out of the box